# How to create loading bar on terminal while OpenCV face recognizer is loading a pretrained yml file (Python)?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a face recognition project, I have created a face recognizer trained model using openCV's built in face recognizer and saved it as .yml format.
In my main project i have to load the .yml file and start my camera to recognize the faces from video capturing.
In order to make it attractive I wanted to add a progress bar while the .yml file is being loaded by the system I dont know how to do it while my system is loading the file, any help will be much appreciated.

```
face_recognizer = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
face_recognizer.train(features,labels)
face_recognizer.save('face_trainedV2.0.yml')
```

The above code is what I used to create a trained model. Where **features** and **labels** are the faces and respective names(Which are represented as numbers) of the persons.

```
face_recognizer = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
face_recognizer.read('face_trainedV2.0.yml')
```

In my main project I have loaded the trained model like shown above, and I want to add the progress bar on the terminal while the program is reading the pretrained model. As it is a huge file (aroung 250mb) the program is taking more time to read the file that is also a reason I want to display progress bar.

Comment: have you tried [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/) ?

Comment: No I will try and also can i able to implement both progress bar and loading .yml file at the same time ?